# How can I use vb variable in javascript using asp.net web forms?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

So, this is how my program looks like

[image]

The VB coding behind this is

```
Imports WebApplication1.login
Public Class Main
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim CleanRubric
    Dim XRubric
    Dim YRubric
    Dim Score = WebApplication1.login.Score
    CleanRubric = Rubric.Split(":")
    XRubric = Rubric(0)
    YRubric = Rubric(2)
    Label1.Text = "Hello! , Welcome: " & FullName & ", Here is your Report"
    Label2.Text = "Your Score: " & Score
    Label3.Text = "Notes: " & Notes
    Label4.Text = "Domain Notes: " & D_Notes
    Label5.Text = "X Rubric score is: " & XRubric
    Label6.Text = "Y Rubric score is: " & YRubric
    Label7.Text = "Does the teacher need to see you? " & UrgentChecker(Urgent)

End Sub
Function UrgentChecker(ByVal Urgent As Integer)
    If Urgent = 1 Then
        Return "Yes"
    ElseIf Urgent = 0 Then
        Return "No"
    Else
        Return "---Error--- : Please See Teacher"
    End If
End Function
End Class
```

Now, the html and javascript code is...

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Main.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.Main" runat="server"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Results</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme2.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/3/gauge.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/dark.js"></script>

<!-- amCharts javascript code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--var score = document.getElementById("<%=Label2.ClientID%>").innerHTML;-->
    AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv",
        {
            "type": "gauge",
            "pathToImages": "amcharts/images/",
            "faceBorderAlpha": 2,
            "faceBorderWidth": 2,
            "marginBottom": 0,
            "marginTop": 40,
            "startDuration": 0,
            "color": "#E7E7E7",
            "fontSize": 9,
            "handDrawScatter": 0,
            "theme": "dark",
            "arrows": [
                {
                    "axis": "Not set",
                    "id": "GaugeArrow-1",
                    "nailAlpha": 0.44,
                    "nailBorderAlpha": 0.58,
                    "nailBorderThickness": 5,
                    "nailRadius": 30,
                    "radius": "98%",
                    "startWidth": 12,
                    "value": 2
                }
            ],
            "axes": [
                {
                    "axisThickness": 1,
                    "bottomText": "Score",
                    "bottomTextFontSize": 18,
                    "bottomTextYOffset": 25,
                    "endAngle": 112,
                    "endValue": 4,
                    "id": "GaugeAxis-1",
                    "topTextFontSize": -1,
                    "topTextYOffset": -4,
                    "valueInterval": 1,
                    "bands": [
                        {
                            "alpha": 0.7,
                            "color": "#00CC00",
                            "endValue": 1,
                            "id": "GaugeBand-1",
                            "startValue": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "alpha": 0.7,
                            "color": "#FF0000",
                            "endValue": 2,
                            "id": "GaugeBand-2",
                            "startValue": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "alpha": 0.7,
                            "color": "#0000FF",
                            "endValue": 3,
                            "id": "GaugeBand-3",
                            "startValue": 2
                        },
                        {
                            "alpha": 0.7,
                            "color": "#DAA520",
                            "endValue": 4,
                            "id": "GaugeBand-4",
                            "startValue": 3
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "allLabels": [],
            "balloon": {
                "offsetX": 12
            },
            "titles": []
        }
    );
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <h1>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </h1>
```

I want it to represent the value of the students score, I added

`var score = document.getElementById("<%=Label2.ClientID%>").innerHTML;`
But my graph immediately disappeared like this

[image]

help :) 
(The student names are different in pictures that is fine, thats all database stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create public property named `Score`, or change that score from `Dim` to `Public` , declare outside page_load and inside the class.

Then use that variable in aspx like this - `var score = "<%=Score%>";`.

Like following

```
Public Class Main
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Public Score = WebApplication1.login.Score

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim CleanRubric
    Dim XRubric
    Dim YRubric

    CleanRubric = Rubric.Split(":")
```

Comment: Error: Public is not valid on a local variable declaration

Comment: @RedderLopez, please read the instruction - `declare outside page_load and inside the class.`. See the updated answer..

Comment: @RedderLopez, it is obvious that you are not debuging or looking at right thing to fix, instead of looking into graph, see if that value is set or not!

Comment: @RedderLopez, Dim variables are not accessible in `aspx` , that is why I told  to declare as Public and public has to be outsite of any event.

Answer (score 1):

```
var score = document.getElementById("Label2").innerText;
```

Edit:

ASP.NET

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), Nothing, "test();", True)
End Sub
```

JavaScript

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var score;
    function test() {
        score = document.getElementById("Label2").innerText;
        AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv",
    {
        "type": "gauge",
        "pathToImages": "amcharts/images/",
        "faceBorderAlpha": 2,
        "faceBorderWidth": 2,
        "marginBottom": 0,
        "marginTop": 40,
        "startDuration": 0,
        "color": "#E7E7E7",
        "fontSize": 9,
        "handDrawScatter": 0,
        "theme": "dark",
        "arrows": [
            {
                "axis": "Not set",
                "id": "GaugeArrow-1",
                "nailAlpha": 0.44,
                "nailBorderAlpha": 0.58,
                "nailBorderThickness": 5,
                "nailRadius": 30,
                "radius": "98%",
                "startWidth": 12,
                "value": 2
            }
        ],
        "axes": [
            {
                "axisThickness": 1,
                "bottomText": "Score",
                "bottomTextFontSize": 18,
                "bottomTextYOffset": 25,
                "endAngle": 112,
                "endValue": 4,
                "id": "GaugeAxis-1",
                "topTextFontSize": -1,
                "topTextYOffset": -4,
                "valueInterval": 1,
                "bands": [
                    {
                        "alpha": 0.7,
                        "color": "#00CC00",
                        "endValue": 1,
                        "id": "GaugeBand-1",
                        "startValue": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "alpha": 0.7,
                        "color": "#FF0000",
                        "endValue": 2,
                        "id": "GaugeBand-2",
                        "startValue": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "alpha": 0.7,
                        "color": "#0000FF",
                        "endValue": 3,
                        "id": "GaugeBand-3",
                        "startValue": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "alpha": 0.7,
                        "color": "#DAA520",
                        "endValue": 4,
                        "id": "GaugeBand-4",
                        "startValue": 3
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "allLabels": [],
        "balloon": {
            "offsetX": 12
        },
        "titles": []
    }
);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Did not work, as soon as I added that line 
http://gyazo.com/81901528b58512b4ac08a05a6d487f73

Graph disappeared

Comment: Ok, make a function that contains the AmCharts.makeChart call, and call the function from Page Load event

Comment: What do you mean? , Can you give me example please, im new to all this.

Comment: The graph disappeared again

Comment: When The graph disappeared ? When you do what ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var score = document.getElementById("<%=Label2.ClientID%>").innerHTML;
```

This code does work. You have to call it after the values have already been set. Have you tried moving your javascript to the bottom of the page?

Comment: Transferring my code to the bottom does not work, I just get a value of 0
http://gyazo.com/eadcb816a2bc8fa664e04637bf0c8387